# Shapeless - Generic Repr Type manipulation

Tags: scala, shapeless

If I have a method such as:

```
        def f[T: Generic, U: Generic](t: T): U
```

`Generic[T].to(t)` returns type `Generic[T]#Repr` which I assume is a type alias for some type of HList.

Is it possible to select members from the `HList` and build another `HList` which I can convince the compiler is of type `Generic[U]#Repr` which I can then use to create an instance of `U` using `Generic[U].from(myNewHList)`?

I have tried many approaches but seem to be going around in circles.

Comment: Do you know that the elements of U are a subset of T? What do you want to happen if U contains elements not it T?

Comment: Yes. That has already been validated.

Comment: "already been validated" but Shapeless doesn't really work that way—you have to drag around the evidence for the rest of eternity.

Answer (score 3):

When doing stuff like this in Shapeless, the best place to look is in the `shapeless.ops` typeclasses. In this case, since you know your second class is a strict subset of your first, `Intersection` is sufficient to get what you want. You'll want to set this up as a type class, so that you can pass in your input and output types and let the compiler infer the intermediate stuff.

```
trait Converter[A,B] {
  def convert(a: A): B
}
object Converter {
  def apply[A,B](implicit converter: Converter[A,B]) = converter

  implicit def genericConverter[A, B, ARepr <: HList, BRepr <: HList](
    implicit
    genA: Generic.Aux[A,ARepr],
    genB: Generic.Aux[B,BRepr],
    intersection: shapeless.ops.hlist.Intersection.Aux[ARepr,BRepr,BRepr]
  ): Converter[A,B] = 
    new Converter[A,B]{def convert(a: A): B = genB.from(intersection(genA.to(a)))}
}
```

This can be used as follows:

```
case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int, c: String)
case class Bar(a: Int, c: String)
val foo = Foo(1,2,"Three")
val bar: Bar = Converter[Foo, Bar].convert(foo)
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this - shapeless.ops looks like a great place to look for examples. My first use case is where the fields in T are a superset of those in U however I plan to extend the API to allow allow the user to add columns that do not exist on T aor allow implicit conversions between columns on T -> U. I guess I still need to be able to create/manipulate and pass arbitrary HLists in order to do so but hopefully shapeless.ops gives me some ideas.

Comment: You should check out the Type Astronaut's Guide to Shapeless: https://books.underscore.io/shapeless-guide/shapeless-guide.html. They pretty much cover your exact use case as an example.

Comment: Downloaded and will read at work today! I guess I saw the List part HList and just assumed this would simple. I am glad I have found a reason to use shapeless and am sure it will up my game scala wise.

Comment: Is it possible to somehow use the `T : Generic` notation and somehow specify the `Generic[T]#Repr` is a `HList`? If possible I really need to avoid having to specify a `TRepr <: HList` type parameter and using `Generic.Aux[T, TRepr]`

Comment: Since the `ops.hlist.Intersection` typeclass requires an `HList`, that's unfortunately not possible, since a `Generic` representation might also be a `Coproduct`. Why do you need to work with a `Generic` though? You should be referring to your types, and let the compiler infer the `Generic` instance like above.